# invokeMethod from Groovy with parameters

Tags: java, groovy

I want to invoke groovy method from the given below class

```
 package infa9

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.ABC.csm.context.AppCtxProperties;

import com.ABC.csm.context.AppContext;


 public class LicenseInfo
{
private StringBuffer licenseInformation;

public LicenseInfo() {
    licenseInformation = new StringBuffer();
}

public StringBuffer getLicenseInformation(){
    return licenseInformation;
}

public void fetchLicenseInformation(HashMap<String,String> params,Map env)
{
    ArrayList<String> licenseList = fetchLicenses(params);
    .
    .
    .

}

private ArrayList<String> fetchLicenses(HashMap<String,String> params,Map env)
{

    ArrayList<String>licenseList = new ArrayList<String>();
    .
    .
    .
return licenseList;

}

}
```

So this is what I am trying to do

```
//getting user parameters
HashMap<String,String> params = IntermediateResults.get("userparams")

//getting environment variables
Map env=AppContext.get(AppCtxProperties.environmentVariables)

Object[] arguments=new Object[2]
arguments.putAt("userparams", params)
arguments.putAt("env", env)

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
Script infa9LicenseScript = shell.parse("plugins.infa9.LicenseInfo")

   infa9LicenseScript.invokeMethod(fetchLicenseInformation, arguments)
   String lic=(String)infa9LicenseScript.invokeMethod(getLicenseInformation,null)
```

Am I passing the parameters to `fetchLicenseInformation` correctly?? I need to pass `HashMap<String,String> ,Map` Please help me invoke a groovy method with parameters

Error: `Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: userparams for class: [Ljava.lang.Object;`

**Update**

```
public List<String> fetchLicenses( Map<String,String> params, Map env ) {
//[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
  ArrayList<String>licenseList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String infacmdListLicensesCommand = null;

    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Win"))
    {   infacmdListLicensesCommand = env.get("INFA_HOME")
                + "/isp/bin/infacmd.bat ListLicenses -dn "
                + params.get("dn") + " -un " + params.get("un") + " -pd "
                + params.get("pd") + " -sdn " + params.get("sdn") + " -hp "
                + params.get("dh") + ":" + params.get("dp");}
    else
    {   infacmdListLicensesCommand = env.get("INFA_HOME")
                + "/isp/bin/infacmd.sh ListLicenses -dn "  //this is line no 71, where exception is thrown
                + params.get("dn") + " -un " + params.get("un") + " -pd "
                + params.get("pd") + " -sdn " + params.get("sdn") + " -hp "
                + params.get("dh") + ":" + params.get("dp");}

    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(infacmdListLicensesCommand);

        InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            licenseList.add(line);
        }
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exit value is: " + exitVal);

    }catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    } /* end catch */
return licenseList;
 }
```

**Exception**
`Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.positive() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: notify(), tokenize(), size()
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unaryPlus(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:764)
        at infa9.LicenseInfo.fetchLicenses(Infa9LicensesUtil.groovy:71)`

Comment: Is this all in groovy?  The `LicenseInfo` class looks like Java?  Then again, the code you are trying to run looks like Java too...  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: I starting groovy so sometimes I mix up with the syn-taxes.. I have updated my question with `Error` at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right...I created this groovy script `LicenseInfo.groovy` inside a folder `./test/`:

```
package test

public class LicenseInfo {
  StringBuffer licenseInformation

  public LicenseInfo() {
    licenseInformation = new StringBuffer()
  }

  public void fetchLicenseInformation( Map<String,String> params, Map env ) {
    List<String> licenseList = fetchLicenses( params, env )
    println "List is $licenseList"
  }

  public List<String> fetchLicenses( Map<String,String> params, Map env ) {
    [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
  }
}
```

inside the current folder `./`, I created this groovy script `Test.groovy`:

```
// Make some params...
def params = [ name:'tim', value:'text' ]

// Fake an env Map
def env = [ something:'whatever' ]

// Load the class from the script
def liClass = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass( new File( 'test/LicenseInfo.groovy' ) )

// Run the method
liClass.newInstance().fetchLicenseInformation( params, env )
```

When I execute the command

```
groovy Test.groovy
```

it prints out:

```
List is [a, b, c]
```

### Edit after update

The `positive` errors you are getting are due to the way the Groovy parser works...  You cannot put the `+` on the start of the next line when joining Strings, the `+` has to be trailing on the previous line (as semi-colons are optional for the end of lines in groovy, there is no way for the parser to know you are adding on to the previous line)

This will work:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Win")) {
  infacmdListLicensesCommand = env.get("INFA_HOME") + "/isp/bin/infacmd.bat ListLicenses -dn " +
                               params.get("dn") + " -un " + params.get("un") + " -pd " +
                               params.get("pd") + " -sdn " + params.get("sdn") + " -hp " +
                               params.get("dh") + ":" + params.get("dp")
}
else {
  infacmdListLicensesCommand = env.get("INFA_HOME") + "/isp/bin/infacmd.sh ListLicenses -dn " +
                               params.get("dn") + " -un " + params.get("un") + " -pd " +
                               params.get("pd") + " -sdn " + params.get("sdn") + " -hp " +
                               params.get("dh") + ":" + params.get("dp")
}
```

And this would be a more *Groovy* way of doing the same thing:

```
boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Win")
// Do it as a list of 3 items for formatting purposes
infacmdListLicensesCommand = [
  "$env.INFA_HOME/isp/bin/infacmd.${isWindows?'bat':'sh'} ListLicenses"
  "-dn $params.dn -un $params.un -pd $params.pd -sdn $params.sdn"
  "-hp $params.dh:$params.dp" ].join( ' ' ) // then join them back together

println infacmdListLicensesCommand // print it out to see it's the same as before
```

Comment: Still no luck.. also I changed my path to `plugins/infa9/LicenseInfo`

Comment: Updated my answer with a complete solution

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Hope it helped!

Comment: Although I marked your answer correct, I still need 1 more help, please check my `update` part, I get a error in one of the functions

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Which update part?  The `MissingPropertyException`?  That's because you're trying to use an Object array as a Map.  See how I construct my `params` variable in the code above.  That's how you should construct your `arguments` variable I believe

Comment: Sorry for late update post.. I have updated my question with the exception thrown and the code, and yes your are right, i was creating a map.. so i rectified it

Comment: @AbhishekSimon added an update to the answer to explain what the probelm was... and maybe a better way of doing it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion over improving over my code, here is what i followed to clear the [exception] (http://developer.partnersoft.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Java.lang.String.positive()_is_applicable_for_argument_types:_()_values&printable=yes)

Comment: Hi tim, I need your help in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626414/why-is-my-groovy-shell-output-coming-different-from-the-console-command-output) which has code from your answer, can you help? Thanks again