# Run function with multiple values

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I’ve function like the following

```
def runTestsInDocker(arg) {
    measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
        executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage,  dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
            sh """
            mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoPro
            go ${arg}                        
            """
        }
    }
```

When I’ve only 1 parameter this is working as expected
Now I want to add new parameters so I can do something like this

```
def runTestsInDocker(arg,arg2,arg3) {
    measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
        executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage,  dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
            sh """
            mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoPro

            go ${arg}  
           go ${arg1}
           go ${arg2}
            """
        }
    }
```

But here I’ve two problems

1 . What happen if I need to pass only one parameter?

2. If I’ve 10 parameters to pass I will have 10 args?

Is there a nicer way in groovy to handle it ?

**update** , let's say I need to call to the function with 1 parameters

```
   def runTestsInDocker(Map<String,String> params) {
        measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
            executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage,  dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
                sh """
                mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoPro

                go ${params.get('arg')}  

                """
            }
        }
```

And other function

```
   def runTestsInDocker(Map<String,String> params) {
        measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
            executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage,  dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
                sh """
                mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoPro

                go ${params.get('arg')}  
                go ${params.get('arg1')} 
                """
            }
        }
```

I don't know in advance how much parameters I will need to use, so how can I do it dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send `Map` to method to invoke [multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568120/invokemethod-from-groovy-with-parameters)

```
def runTestsInDocker( Map<String,String> params) {
```

and call it using a Map:

```
def params = [ arg:'value', arg1:'value1' ];
runTestsInDocker(params);
```

Inside method iterate through map dynamically as:

```
params.each{ k, v -> go ${v} }
```

Comment: Thanks but how should I call it insdie the function ?

Comment: @shopiaT get specific value or iterate over map

Comment: I mean like this             `go ${arg}  
           go ${arg1}
           go ${arg2}`

Comment: @shopiaT as go param.get('arg')

Comment: How can I check that `param.get('arg')` is not empty ?

Comment: @shopiaT `param.get('arg')?` or using `if (param.get('arg')!= null)` for example

Comment: But now it get a bit messy :) , how would you run this for two diffrent functions 1 with two args and other for more then one ...

Comment: @shopiaT iterate through map as `params.each{ k, v -> go ${v} }`. see more in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037374/loop-through-map-in-groovy

Comment: it will be great if you can update your answer and I close the question as resolved, that other can learn from...thanks!

Comment: Thanks , since I im inside `sh """`  should I change it ?

Comment: this is not working `params.each{ k, v -> go ${v} }` :(

Comment: do you have any idea ? this is indeed working`make ${params.get('arg')}`

Comment: @shopiaT do it outside `sh` , if it doesn't work I think you should open another question about how the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your target example, this looks like a perfect case for [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

```
def runTestsInDocker(String... args) {
    measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
        executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage, dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
            sh """
            mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoPro
            go ${args.join('\ngo ')}
            """
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to only pass parameters at certain position, this method signature allows that as well.

```
runTestsInDocker(null,'foo',null,'bar')
// OR
def args = []
args[2] = 'foo'
args[5] = 'bar'
runTestsInDocker(args as String[])
```

If, for some reason, you really want parameters with different names and semantics, then I would look into following:

- Default values, like `runTestsInDocker(String arg = null, String arg1 = null, String arg2 = null)`
- Map parameter, like `runTestsInDocker(Map map)`
- POGO parameter, like `runTestsInDocker(MyPogo args)`. Compared to map, this provides type checking and it is very easy to construct a POGO with just the values you need.

Comment: can you please explain on this `go ${args.join('\ngo ')}` ? why there is `\ngo`?

Comment: '\n' is newline character. After that, another 'go '. So, if you join 'a','b' and 'c' with '\ngo ', you will get 'a\ngo b\ngo c' where \n starts a new line.